# Jquery won't recognize variable in a <%=%> scriptlet tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have following (simplified) code:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    <%String lookupcode = "test";%>
    var code= <%=lookupcode%>;
    alert(code);
}
```

What is wrong with this code, why won't he alert the code?

Comment: Is the code a string value?  Do you check for JavaScript errors in the Error Console when you preview the page in your browser?

Answer (score 7):

As `lookupcode` is a string variable, you need to surround the embedded variable in quotes in your javascript:

```
var code= '<%=lookupcode%>';
```